# How do I tokenize a string sentence in NLTK?

Tags: python, nlp, tokenize, nltk

I am using nltk, so I want to create my own custom texts just like the default ones on nltk.books. However, I've just got up to the method like

```
my_text = ['This', 'is', 'my', 'text']
```

I'd like to discover any way to input my "text" as:

```
my_text = "This is my text, this is a nice way to input text."
```

Which method, python's or from nltk allows me to do this. And more important, how can I dismiss punctuation symbols?

Comment: Could you clarify, what do you mean by `underestimate punctation symbols` ?

Comment: i think he meant to tokenize the input sentence

Comment: Yeah, for example if I did:

sentente = "This is my sentence, a sentence is a short expression"

So, 'sentence,' and 'sentence' would be two different elements ...

Answer (score 169, accepted):

This is actually on the [main page of nltk.org](http://nltk.org/):

```
>>> import nltk
>>> sentence = """At eight o'clock on Thursday morning
... Arthur didn't feel very good."""
>>> tokens = nltk.word_tokenize(sentence)
>>> tokens
['At', 'eight', "o'clock", 'on', 'Thursday', 'morning',
'Arthur', 'did', "n't", 'feel', 'very', 'good', '.']
```

Comment: the problem is that it doesn't split /.  If you have "today and/or tomorrow are good days", it gives "and/or" as a single token by default.

Comment: how do we convert "n't" to "not"?

Comment: @Omayr, I would use regular expressions to convert "n't" to "not". I have attached some sample code below.    { re.sub("'t", 'ot', "n't, doesn't, can't, don't")} **bold**

Comment: I was using word_tokenize in Python2, but in Python3 I would like to have a list of bytes, not strings. Is it possible?

Answer (score -7):

As @PavelAnossov answered, the canonical answer, use the `word_tokenize` function in nltk:

```
from nltk import word_tokenize
sent = "This is my text, this is a nice way to input text."
word_tokenize(sent)
```

---

**If your sentence is truly simple enough:**

Using the `string.punctuation` set, remove punctuation then split using the whitespace delimiter:

```
import string
x = "This is my text, this is a nice way to input text."
y = "".join([i for i in x if not in string.punctuation]).split(" ")
print y
```

Comment: @pavel's answer will resolve problems like `didn't` -> `did` + `n't`

Comment: What are the issues with `word_tokenize`? Seeing there are so many downvotes, I want to make sure I didn't miss something.

Comment: I didn't downvote, but I'm guessing your answer is essentially a copy of Pavel's answer. Maybe a comment on his answer would have been more appropriate.