# How can I split a sentence into indivdual words with punctuation?

Tags: python-3.x

Using Python 3.x, I need to split a sentence up into individual words and punctuation.

e.g.\ "This is a sentence."

split up into

["This", "is", "a", "sentence", "."]

I'm trying to match words using a for loop, however if I try to match the word "sentence" it doesn't match because when I .split() on whitespace it makes it "sentence." instead of "sentence" and won't match because of the punctuation. What would be the best way to go about doing this?

Comment: Add punctuation to the list of tokens to split on.  Should be a regex: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10974932/python-split-string-based-on-regular-expression

Comment: Use a tokenizer: http://www.nltk.org/api/nltk.tokenize.html

Comment: Indeed, don't try to reinvent the wheel: the [nltk toolkit's Punkt tokenizer](http://www.nltk.org/api/nltk.tokenize.html#module-nltk.tokenize.punkt) works fairly well.

Comment: And check out this [question/answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15057945/how-do-i-tokenize-a-string-sentence-in-nltk) which gives an example of the nltk tokenizer.

Answer (score 0):

Use split(" .,:") and whatever other separators you'd like.

Comment: with `s = "this is also a sentence, really"`, `s.split(" .,;")` will result in `['this is also a sentence, really']`, because you split on the combination " .,;".